# insert selected image from gridview into db

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to insert selected image from gridview into mysql table. When I try to, it gives me message saying

> An exception of type '**System.InvalidCastException**' occurred in
>   App_Web_zptg3ta3.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional
>   information: Unable to cast object of type '**System.Int32**' to type
>   'System.Data.DataRow'.

Below is my c# & markup code:

```
if (gvImages.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    DataRow SelectedRowValue = ((DataRow)gvImages.SelectedValue);
byte[] ImageBytes = (byte[])SelectedRowValue.ItemArray[1];
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO rasmlar (Rasm) VALUES (@ImageSource)", con);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ImageSource", MySqlDbType.Blob, ImageBytes.Length).Value = ImageBytes;
    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

<asp:GridView ID="gvImages" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" 
                        DataKeyNames="Rasm_ID" AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" AllowPaging="True" 
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnPageIndexChanging="gvImages_PageIndexChanging" 
                        PageSize="5" SelectedIndex="1">
                       <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rasm_ID">
                                <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rasm_ID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rasm_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rasm">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="80" Width="80" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                        </Columns>
                        <selectedrowstyle backcolor="LightCyan" forecolor="DarkBlue" font-bold="true"/>                           
                        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: show your gridview markup please

Answer (score 0):

A lot of your code looks incorrect to me. Starting with:

```
DataRow SelectedRowValue = ((DataRow)gvImages.SelectedValue);
```

`GridView.SelectedValue` is not what you want. I believe you want `GridView.SelectedRow`:

```
GridViewRow row = gvImages.SelectedRow;

// Change `.Cells[5]` to the correct cell index.
byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[])row.Cells[5].Value;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
```